# How to make my Spyder code run on GPU instead of cpu on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, deep-learning

I am working on Spyder to create deep learning model on a machine have a GPU I have found that am working on a CPU and my code run for a long time.First I downloaded tensorflow-GPU but I don't how to start working on GPU . How to make my Spyder code run on GPU instead of cpu on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You select cpu by explicitly specifying the device like this:

```
with tf.device("cpu"):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
         your code
```

Comment: @Achai Gupta thanks for the solution.Do you mean 
with tf.device("gpu"):
    with tf.Session() as sess:

I want to work on GPU instead of cpu

Comment: @Anchai Gupta It doesn't work. can you help me how to work on GPU ??

Comment: Can you upload output for this to see where is the error?  

**from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib** 

**device_lib.list_local_devices()**

Comment: @Anchai Gupta invalid syntax

Comment: from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

Comment: print(device_lib.list_local_devices())